# "Fill button" animation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uianimation

Do you have any suggestion to implement the following button animation in an iOS app?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok lets split this animation into a few segments to figure it out.

1) We need a white and green circle.
2) We need a tick image.
3) We need to animate the white circle and the tick.

**Step One**

Add a green `UIView` to your interface file. This will be the background view. We do not need to animate this view. Then link the green view to a `IBOutlet` like so:

```
IBOutlet UIView *greenView;
```

**Step Two**

Add a white UIView inside of the green `UIView` and make it the exact same size as the green `UIView`. Then link the white `UIView` to an `IBOutlet` in you header file like so:

```
IBOutlet UIView *whiteView;
```

**Step Three**

Make or download a 'tick' image and add it to your `Xcode` project. Then add the tick image **ABOVE** the green/white views that we just created. Please place the tick above the views and **NOT** in the views. Then link the tick image to an `IBOutlet` - this will help us detect when the view has been pressed. Do it like so:

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *tickImage;
```

**Step Four**

We need to change the green and white `UIView` to circles. We can do this with code. Import the `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` framework into you header file.

Then in your `viewDidLoad` method, add the following code which will change the green/white views into circles:

```
    CGPoint greenCenter = greenView.center;
    CGPoint whiteCenter = whiteView.center;

    CGRect newFrameGreen = CGRectMake(greenView.frame.origin.x, greenView.frame.origin.y, 20, 20);

    CGRect newFrameWhite = CGRectMake(whiteView.frame.origin.x, greenView.frame.origin.y, 20, 20);

    greenView.frame = newFrameGreen;
    greenView.layer.cornerRadius = newSize / 2.0;
    greenView.center = greenCenter;

    whiteView.frame = newFrameWhite;
    whiteView.layer.cornerRadius = newSize / 2.0;
    whiteView.center = whiteCenter;
```

**Step Five**

In order to run the animation, we need to connect the image view to a method which will run the animation. You can do it by using a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. In your `viewDidLoad` method, add the following:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *newTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tickAnimation)];
[tickImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[tickImage addGestureRecognizer:newTap];
```

Then add the animation method to you implementation (.m) file as well:

```
-(void)tickAnimation {
    }
```

**Step Six**

Create a `BOOL` value in your header file - we will use this to detect if the button is in the "ON" or "OFF" states.

```
BOOL animationMode;
```

Then in your `viewDidLoad` method, set the animationMode bool value to "OFF" - this is because the button will be "OFF" or in the white state by default.

```
animationMode = NO;
```

Now we can go on to the animation. From what I can see, this is split up into two animations. The first one is making the white view smaller and the second one is doing a subtle popup animation on the tick image. Update the `tickAnimation` method in order to perform the animation:

```
-(void)tickAnimation {

    if (animationMode == NO) {

        // Button is OFF or set to white, lets set it to ON.

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
             whiteView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0,0);
        } completion:nil];

         [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
              tickImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2,2);
         } completion:nil];

         [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
              tickImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0,0);
         } completion:nil];

         animationMode = YES;
    }

    else if (animationMode == YES) {

        // Button is ON or set to green, lets set it to OFF.

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
             whiteView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);
        } completion:nil];

        animationMode = NO;
    }
}
```

This is my attempt at making this kind of animation. I hope this helps :)

Comment: what is newsize here?? :) @dan

Comment: @FionaShoff Oh sorry, just replace it with a value like 10.

Comment: Sorry I dont wanna use IBOutlet. Please help me with full code :) i will be grateful to you @dan

Comment: @FionaShoff Why don't you want to use ```IBOutlet``` ?

Comment: @Dan: if you do tickImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0,0), the image will not be visible anymore and you can't press it again, for the animation.

Answer (score 4):

You could animate the `layer.borderWidth` property for the colour fill.. It draws inside of the layer, something like this.

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 100, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:button];

button.layer.borderWidth = 10;
button.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
button.layer.cornerRadius = 50;

CABasicAnimation *border = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"borderWidth"];
[border setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]];
[border setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:50]];
border.duration = 1.0;
button.layer.borderWidth = 50;

[button.layer addAnimation:border forKey:@"border"];
```

Here is a really slow gif screen cap of this working with `autoReverse` set to true.

[image: UIBorder animation]

---

**If you like Swift it looks like this**

```
var button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 100, height: 100))
self.view.addSubview(button)

button.layer.borderWidth = 10
button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
button.layer.cornerRadius = 50

let border:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderWidth")
border.fromValue = 10
border.toValue = 50
border.duration = 1.0
button.layer.borderWidth = 50

button.layer.addAnimation(border, forKey: "border")
```

Comment: The question is in ```Objective-C```.

Comment: Ah whoops, will convert.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have an imageView with image like this.

[image]

Second, you overlay it with a white `UIView`, and at the same time, init a `UIImageview` for the v symbol to turn it into white color.

Next step, run animation to scale the white view from 1 to 0 in 0.2 sec.
When it done, you run other animation to make the white v symbol scale from 1 to 1.2 in 0.2 sec.

That is my idea.

Comment: It clearly uses a mask. that would not produce the same effect, but it's a very simple and interesting way to achieve that animation.

Comment: With the complex image and want to convert to code, I advice to use PaintCode. But it must pay money for that. So my idea is just the simplest way to do that, and save money :D